# Can't access private ip from pod even after creating service and endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Service manifest

```yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: alloydb
spec:
 ports:
 - port: 5432
   targetPort: 5432
   protocol: TCP
```

Endpoint manifest

```yaml
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
 name: alloydb
subsets:
 - addresses:
     - ip: 10.60.242.7  # IP of your desire end point
   ports:
     - port: 5432     # Port that you want to access
```

Output of `kubectl get svc`

```
> k get svc

NAME                            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
alloydb                         ClusterIP   10.107.254.93    <none>        5432/TCP         5m38s
```

Output of `kubectl get ep`.

```
> kubectl get ep

NAME                            ENDPOINTS                            AGE
alloydb                         10.60.242.7:5432                     6m7s
```

Output of `kubectl get netpol`

```
> kubectl get netpol

No resources found in default namespace.
```

Now, trying to test it from a temporary ubuntu pod but it's not working.

```bash
root@ubuntu:/# telnet alloydb 5432
Trying 10.107.254.93...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

As we can see, service name is getting resolved to service ip but it gets stuck there somehow. How can we debug this?

That private ip is accessible from the node. If I create a deployment with `network: host`, then also it works, but that not I want to do.

Update: added more info

Comment: can you add `kubectl get netpol` output here ?

Comment: I get `No resources found in default namespace.`

Comment: and both pods(including the temp ubuntu pod used for telnet) running in the default namespace?

Comment: the other one is not a pod. it's Google's new database(alloydb).. for now you can think of it as cloud sql for postres with private ip.

Comment: can you share the output of `telnet 10.60.242.7 5432` from that temp ubuntu pod?

Comment: It's inaccessible `root@ubuntu:/# telnet 10.60.242.7 5432
Trying 10.60.242.7...`

Comment: So, it's not related to service or the endpoint resource configuration. This IP or port or both don't seem to be reachable from inside the pods. Does this private ip db instance allow traffic from the k8s cluster over port 5432? Or Do you have a NetworkPolicy configured in that namespace that restricts outbound connections?

Comment: Why do you create the endpoints yourself? Second thing I would try to test curl -s localhost:5432 within the pod itself to verify that the service is running

Comment: `Does this private ip db instance allow traffic from the k8s cluster over port 5432?` Yes. that's why I'm able to access that from node. `Or Do you have a NetworkPolicy configured in that namespace that restricts outbound connections? ` No. output of `k get netpol` is empty..

Comment: @CodeWizard read this [section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

Comment: @Krishna - Taking a step back, are you trying to access an instance of AlloyDB (https://cloud.google.com/alloydb) from a pod?  And are you trying to use private service access to connect?

Comment: @GariSingh yes. exactly.

Comment: Super late to this party (sorry, missed it somehow). Is the GKE deployment and the AlloyDB cluster on the same VPC/network? If no, that's the issue. If yes, can you create a GCE instance on the same network as both (being sure to open the firewall egress so it can get out to the AlloyDB cluster) and see if you can reach it from there with the psql client?